# Android Send files via Bluetooth programmatically

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have a java android app that list all nearby Bluetooth active devices, and the user can pair with a device.
I want to make the user when is paired with another device to send files or images via Bluetooth.
How can I achieve that in android (java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this over classic Bluetooth, have a look at the following links:-

- [Bluetooth file transfer for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748219/bluetooth-file-transfer-android)
- [Android Bluetooth file sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502497/android-bluetooth-file-sending)
- [How can I send a file through bluetooth with Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195650/how-can-i-send-a-file-through-bluetooth-with-android-devices/21365372)
- [Android: Send image via Bluetooth](http://kpbird.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-send-image-via-bluetooth.html)

If you're doing this via Bluetooth Low Energy, have a look at the following links:-

- [The ultimate guide to Android BLE development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Bluetooth LE send string data between two devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636725/bluetooth-le-send-string-data-between-android-devices-via-application)
- [Transfer image through BLE in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57758397/transfer-image-throug-ble-in-android)